# AWS Transcribe: Fails with ('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I am able to run polly from the command line but the same time when I try to use AWS Transcribe I get a connection reset error

JSON:

```
JSON received: {
    "TranscriptionJobName": "test",
    "LanguageCode": "en-US",
    "MediaSampleRateHertz": 24000,
    "MediaFormat": "mp3",
    "Media": {
        "MediaFileUri": "https://filename.mp3"
    }
}
```

Command Line:

```
aws transcribe start-transcription-job --region 'us-east-1' --cli-input-json file://test.json
```

Output:

```
('Connection aborted.', error(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Any direction as to how I can know more about the error.

Answer (score 0):

That error means the remote SSL certificate could not be validated. Double check the remote certificate. Also try using a plain http endpoint if available, rather than https.

NOTE: RE MediaFileUri": "https://filename.mp3" in your example. The URI would always have a host specificaton; it does not have one here just fyi

Edit Try https://www.ssllabs.com or https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html for SSL testing.

Comment: Any pointers where I can check the remote certificate?
As for the second part, I edited the URI to post it here, but otherwise it a valid URi with host specification.

Comment: Added some links. Also try openssl s_client -connect www.server.com:443

Comment: Did you try http only?